# rmarkdown bibliography with user defined template

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

given the following reproducible example:

````
---
title: "pdf output by user defined tex template"
output:
    pdf_document:
      template: default.latex
#bibliography: bib.bib
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# About Pandoc metadata

https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-for-latex

# Default tex templates

https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-template.html

The default LaTeX template of Pandoc can be found at.

https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/tree/master/data/templates (named default.latex).

If you want to create your own template, you may want to start with this template.

# A reference to be cited in bibliography
here it is: @R-base

# References
````

- when I un-comment the "bibliography" yaml metadata I get the following error:

! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

on the other hand:

- when I comment out the "template" yaml metadata, but leaving un-commented the "bibliography", I get a correct listing of the references within the relevant section

the template I'm using (starting from) is the default LateX template of Pandoc found at:
https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/main/data/templates/default.latex

the bib file is containing just the following entry:

```
@Manual{R-base,
  title = {R: A Language and Environment for Statistical
           Computing},
  author = {{R Core Team}},
  organization = {R Foundation for Statistical Computing},
  address = {Vienna, Austria},
  year = {2019},
  url = {https://www.R-project.org},
}
```

my question is:

how to get a correct listing of the references in the case of a user defined "template" (which later I'm planning to customise to my needs with other variables)?

Should I enter something in the template file?
And eventually how-to?

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have:

```bash
[ R Markdown Document ]
   |                |
   |--- [YAML Metadata]
   |       |--- [PDF Output]
   |            |--- [Custom Template: default.latex]
   |            |--- [Bibliography: bib.bib (Commented/Uncommented)]
   |
   |--- [Document Content]
         |--- [Citations]
```

You should make sure your custom LaTeX template (`default.latex`) includes the necessary commands to handle bibliographies.

The [Pandoc default LaTeX template](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/main/data/templates/default.latex) you mentioned shows how Pandoc handles bibliographies in LaTeX, and it differs from traditional LaTeX usage.

In this template, bibliography handling is conditional and integrated with Pandoc's templating system. It accommodates both [`natbib`](https://ctan.org/pkg/natbib) and [`biblatex`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) packages for bibliography management.

- If `natbib` is used, the bibliography style is set with `\bibliographystyle{}`, and the bibliography files are included with `\bibliography{}`.
  Example:

  ```latex
  $if(natbib)$
  \usepackage[$natbiboptions$]{natbib}
  \bibliographystyle{$if(biblio-style)$$biblio-style$$else$plainnat$endif$}
  $endif$
  ```
- If `biblatex` is used, bibliography files are added with `\addbibresource{}` and printed with `\printbibliography`.
  Example:

  ```latex
  $if(biblatex)$
  \usepackage[$if(biblio-style)$style=$biblio-style$,$endif$$for(biblatexoptions)$$biblatexoptions$$sep$,$endfor$]{biblatex}
  $for(bibliography)$
  \addbibresource{$bibliography$}
  $endfor$
  $endif$
  ```

The bibliography inclusion in document is:

- for `natbib`, it is included with `\bibliography{$for(bibliography)$$bibliography$$sep$,$endfor$}`.
- for `biblatex`, it is `\printbibliography` within the relevant conditional blocks.

So make sure the YAML header of your R Markdown file specifies which bibliography package (`natbib` or `biblatex`) you are using. Pandoc will use this information to process the bibliography correctly.

If you need to customize the template further, focus on the sections related to the bibliography. You may add or modify conditional statements or settings specific to `natbib` or `biblatex`.

---

Check the YAML header in your R markdown file: uncomment the bibliography line and make sure the path to your `.bib` file is correct.

```yaml
---
title: "pdf output by user defined tex template"
output:
pdf_document:
    template: default.latex
bibliography: bib.bib
---
```

After making these changes, compile your R Markdown document. If the custom template is set up correctly with the bibliography commands, it should generate the PDF with the references correctly formatted.

If you encounter errors, check the LaTeX log for specific messages. Make sure the `.bib` file is correctly formatted, and the citation keys match those used in your document.

Once you have the basic bibliography working, you can continue customizing the template.

Answer (score 2):

the following seems to sort out the problem:

```
---
title: "pdf output by user defined tex template"
output:
    pdf_document:
      template: default.latex
      citation_package: biblatex
bibliography: bib.bib
---
```

without even the need to touch the `default.latex` template (!)

but there is a side effect...

...the reference to a specific citation style in the YAML header through the appropriate metadata i.e. `csl: apa.csl` seems not to affect the  bibliography format in any way;

and now I should probably customise the template... but that's a new problem!
:-(